# how to use HibernateTemplate.find(…) with list

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am new to Hibernate. earlier i am trying using the following query

```
 this.getHibernateTemplate()
      find("select distinct ci.customer " +
             "from CustomerInvoice ci " +
              "where ci.name = ? and ci.id in ? ",name,ids);
```

Where ids is the list of id.It is throwing classCastException. Can someone tell me the    solution with reason

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:40)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:52)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
at org.hibernate.param.PositionalParameterSpecification.bind(PositionalParameterSpecification.java:68)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:578)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
```

Comment: Always paste the complete stack trace of the exception you get. It's helpful. Also, there should be no parentheses around the `?`.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the errors.

Comment: My guess is theat the name argument is a String array, and not a String. Show us how the variables ids and name are declared.

Comment: Well these two parameters are being passed as method parameters  public void getAllowedCustomer(String name, List<String> ids);

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List customers = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List>() {
        @Override
        public List doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Query query = session.createQuery(
                    "select distinct ci.customer " +
                            "from CustomerInvoice ci " +
                            "where ci.name = :name and ci.id in (:ids) "
            );
            query.setParameter("name", name);
            query.setParameterList("ids", ids);
            return query.list();
        }
});
```

1. First of all I think you need to wrap the IN query parameter in (...)
2. You can try with the find() method but if that doesn't know how to apply the list parameter type, you can fall-back to setting it explicitly with "setParameterList" like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try This your error will be solved:

```
this.getHibernateTemplate()
      find("select distinct ci.customer " +
         "from CustomerInvoice ci " +
          "where ci.name = ? and ci.id in ?",new Object[]{name,ids});
```